# Use of Mockito with generic method signatures (java, eclipse) v1.9

Tags: java, generics, mocking, mockito

I cant find an answer already on stackoverlow for this. This is the simplest example I can boil it down to.

I have a class which I want to mock and it places calls to this class

`public class GetCustomerForUser extends PropertyAction<Customer>
    ....`

PropertyAction:

`public abstract class PropertyAction<R> extends AbstractProcessAction<R> implements
      ValuedAction<R, R> {`

The real calling code looks like this

`Customer self = dispatcher.invokeTransactionless(actor, new GetCustomerForUser());`

**dispatcher is of type ActionDispatcher**

In the calling mock

```
    protected void applyWhenClauses(ActionDispatcher dispatcher, Actor actor) throws ProcessException {
        when(dispatcher.invokeTransactionless(actor, (ProcessAction<Customer>) anyObject())).thenReturn(null);
        ....
```

**dispatcher is of type ActionDispatcherMock**

When I run the test I get

```
     org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
     Invalid use of argument matchers!
     2 matchers expected, 1 recorded.
     This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
         //incorrect:
         someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
     When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
     For example:
         //correct:
         someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

     For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.

     at com.prolog.test.mock.ActionDispatcherMock2.applyWhenClauses  
           (ActionDispatcherMock2.java:18)
        at com.prolog.test.mock.ActionDispatcherMock.createMockInstance
           (ActionDispatcherMock.java:84)
at com.prolog.test.mock.ActionDispatcherMock.createMockInstance
           (ActionDispatcherMock.java:1)
at com.prolog.test.mockFactory.AbstractPrologInstanceMock.createInstanceMock
           (AbstractPrologInstanceMock.java:11)
```

I intend to have a when for each class that the dispatcher could invoke.

Does anyone have any words of wisdom about what I'm doing wrong here?

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates what the issue is: if you're using any... `any` you can't then have a not-`any` matcher:

> ```
>  This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
>      //incorrect:
>      someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
>  When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
>  For example:
>      //correct:
>      someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));
> ```

See how you're doing precisely what it says you can't do? And how it says to correct it?

Comment: OK - if I understand correctly you think the problem is actually the "actor" reference?

Comment: Yes. Make it eq(actor). Matchers are those static methods like eq() and anyObject() that define what to expect for a certain parameter. When you pass an object, like actor, Mockito treats that the same as eq(actor). It is like shorthand. But when you pass a matcher explicitly, like anyObject(), your other arguments must be matchers as well so that Mockito can be sure of your intent.

Comment: sorry all - losing my sanity here. Thanks @John Watts for his helpful explanation as I think I hadnt quite understood properly.